# Provide setInterval's ID and clear by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I provide specific ID to `setInterval()` and then call `clearInterval()` by ID.

```
$('.notify').each(function () {
    var chkr = $(this).find('span').text();

    if (chkr == 'Offline') {
        if (typeof(clearC) !== 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(clearC);
        }

        // how can i provide the ID of "clearC" below
        clearC = setInterval(function () {
            soundOn();
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
        //how can i clear "clearC" with the ID provided in if statement
        if (typeof(clearC) !== 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(clearC);
        }
    }
});
```

The Problem is when `if` statement execute then sound goes on. But for next row its enter in `else` statement (because "Online") and clear the interval although it should not be.

**So my concern is** to clear `clearInterval` for specific row until there "Online" text found.

Comment: What isn't working? (There is no ID in set/clear-Interval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this way?

```
$('.notify').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var intervalID = $this.data('intervalID');
    var chkr = $this.find('span').text();

    clearInterval(intervalID);
    if (chkr === 'Offline') {
        $this.data('intervalID', setInterval(function() { soundOn(); }, 500));
    }
});
```

**P.S.** You don't need to check variable with interval ID on `undefined`, there is no real profit in performance, but unnecessary code.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Finally this worked like a charm. BUT why you edited? & remove `else`? it was right

Comment: @RejoanulAlam because it's simply less code. You apply `clearInterval(intervalID)` in both `if` cases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to make sure you keep track of the intervalIds for each of the objects.  So store the intervalId on the objects themselves, using the jQuery .data feature:

```
clearC = setInterval(function () { soundOn(); }, 500);
$(this).data("intervalId", clearC);
```

When you want to retrieve it:

```
clearInterval($(this).data("intervalId"));
```

Comment: no helped. first i need to set a ID to each `setInterval` then i can store it.

Comment: See the change I made.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `clearC` as an object `{}`, create and store its ID in the `.id` property, and `setInterval()` in its `.interval` property. In this way you can check its ID by getting `clearC.id`.

```
var clearC = {};
// ...
$('.notify').each(function(){
  var chkr = $(this).find('span').text();

  if(chkr == 'Offline'){
    if(typeof(clearC.interval) !== 'undefined'){
      clearInterval(clearC.interval);
    }

    // this way you can provide the ID of "clearC.interval" below
    clearC.id = "your-id";
    clearC.interval = setInterval(function () {
      soundOn();
    }, 500);
  }
  else{
    // this way you can clear "clearC.interval" with the ID provided in if statement
    if(typeof(clearC.interval) !== 'undefined'){
      if (clearC.id === "your-id")
        clearInterval(clearC.interval);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This only works for one setInterval, it doesn't work for multiple setInterval calls since we have a loop here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already correct, so I'm a little confused.

It's pretty simple. The id is the return value of `setInterval`. `setInterval` does not accept an id to an existing timer -- what do you expect it would be used for?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval